# Is there a way to transfer game progress from an iOS device to Android

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

I changed from an iPhone to an Android device, is there a way to transfer my progress in Plants vs. Zombies 2 from my old phone to the new one?

Comment: Did you jailbreak the iOS device?

Comment: @RoyalFlush, No

Comment: I am going to guess "no." The game save data is stored in a location that requires root access. Even then, it is protected against tampering because they don't want people to hack in coins and stuff. Yes, you could reverse engineer everything. But that would take more effort than it's worth.

Answer (score 4):

I just did it & no root or jailbreak was needed. Nice.

As suggested above, I extracted the entire library folder to my PC with iFunBox. But the only file needed from the iOS Library folder was "pp.dat".

Then I performed a force-stop of PVZ2 on my Android device before connecting it to my PC via USB. Using Windows Explorer, I navigated to the following Android directory:

Android/data/com.ea.game.pvz2_na/files/No_Backup

The directory contained another file named "pp.dat". I renamed it "pp.dat.bak", just to be safe. I added the iOS file to the Android directory, fired up the game & all of my iPhone progress is now reflected on my Android.

Comment: how exactly you use funbot

Comment: Actually no longer work for IOS 8.3 without jailbreak.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Jailbreak isn't required. Make sure you have the latest version of iTunes & then download [iFunBox](http://i-funbox.com). Then connect your iDevice to the computer and open up iFunBox, select `App`, `PvZ2` and hit "file manager". It'll open up a tab, where  you select your PvZ2 library folder and hit "copy to pc". Copy it to anywhere, but don't mess with it as it contains your saved data. Then replace your PvZ2 library folder on your Android device with the one you saved on your computer using a file manager.

Comment: Where is the library on Android? Is root required?